# Why a past perfect tense is used in a more recent past time event instead of an older past time event?

Tags: grammaticality

The past perfect tense describes an action or event that happens before an action or event in the past tense. However, I found some sentences confusing:

ex: The man arrived at the store before it had opened.

Based on the definition, shouldn't it be "The man *had* arrived at the store before it *opened*"? because the man arrived at the store first and then the store opened?

Another example: My bicycle got a flat tire before we had gone two miles.

Shouldn't it be "My bicycle *had gotten* a flat tire before we *went* two miles?" because the action of the first clause takes place before the second one?

Comment: But the use of the past perfect is not governed by the definition. The definition says what it means when it's used, but not when to use it. Using it is at the discretion of the speaker, since the first-mentioned past event is likely to be in past tense, whatever events may follow it in the sentence.

Comment: Once before, I was told what I had answered was a duplicate and once again I say that I have not seen the kind of "structural" analysis of sequences I have provided.

Comment: The 1st sentence could be rephrased: ***The shore hadn't opened*** *when the man arrived.* And the 2nd: *We had cycled/gone* *less than two miles* ***when*** *my bicycle got a flat tire*.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a quasi-psychological component with reading when examples are given in this pattern.

For example: "Before we had understood anything, the professor went on to new ideas."

Both actions are in the past, but **one precedes the other in the past**. The lack of understanding comes BEFORE the professor went on [in the past] to other things. There are only **two points** on the verbal timeline here: went and what came BEFORE went.

we had not **understood**//the professor **went on**//present time for speaker

1-----------------------------   2 -----------------------------/ PRESENT/FUTURE

The fact the professor went on to other ideas comes AFTER our not understanding. Or conversely, the fact of our not understanding PRECEDED his going on to other ideas.

The OP's example:
My bicycle got a flat tire before we had gone two miles.

1-----------------------------   2 -----------------------------/ PRESENT/FUTURE

1= Before two miles               2=flat tire

The fact of getting a flat tire was preceded by less than two miles of cycling during which there was no flat tire. Conversely, the fact of getting a flat tire came AFTER less than going two miles.

The past perfect refers to the entire time PRECEDING the flat tire, but specifically marks the time up and until the flat tire occurs.

It is a  speaker's choice to use it in contexts like this. A speaker can choose not to use it.

I left the house before the children went to bed.
I left the  house before the children had gone to bed.

Both are grammatical, but they are slightly different in emphasis.